# Why does dereferencing nodes break my linked-list?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I'm trying to implement a run of the mill linked list in C++

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
private:
    Node *next;
    T item;

public:
    Node(T item)
        : item(item)
    {
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    Node<T> add(T item) {
         this->next = new Node(item);
         return *this->next;
    }

    bool hasNext()
    {
        return this->next == NULL;
    }

    Node<T> getNext()
    {
        return *this->next;
    }

    T value()
    {
        return this->item;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Node<int> node(3);
    node.add(3).add(4);

    cout << node.value();
    cout << node.getNext().value();
    cout << node.getNext().getNext().value();

    cin.get();
}
```

but I can't get it to work. In particular this section:

```
    node.add(3).add(4);

    cout << node.value();
    cout << node.getNext().value();
    cout << node.getNext().getNext().value();
```

if I change my `add` and `getNext` functions to return `Node<T>*` instead of `Node<T>`, it works fine. But why does dereferencing cause the code to break? I think the `.` notation makes more sense than `->`, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have `add` return a `Node<T>`, then it returns a _copy_ which you're then modifying. That means that you'll fall off the tail end of the list :-) You're looking for a reference -- return `Node<T>&` on both functions.

Comment: Crap that works, awesome. So do functions in c++ always pass-by-value? (Apologize in advance for my c#/java background)

Comment: Yep. References are pass by, well, reference. A popular use for them is exactly your use-case, and they're also commonly used as `const T&`, so that you get pass-by-reference but ensure that nothing modifies the value.

Comment: @dan.lecocq You were the first to answer - you should have made an answer rather than a comment (unless *Danny* == *dan* :-)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing ring0.

Comment: Ah well :-) Sometimes it's hard to decide what just needs a comment and what needs an answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you are making a copy of the node you added rather than returning the actual node you created. The parenthesis just add a bit of clarity for other people who have to look at your code later. The add function needs to be changed like this:

```
Node<T>& add(T item) {
     this->next = new Node(item);
     return *(this->next);
}
```

or you could return a pointer to the newly created node, but this breaks using the `.` rather than `->` in main.

Also similar changes need to be made to `next()`

Comment: Huh, my C# background got in the way, I see. So c++ always makes a copy (assuming you don't return a pointer or reference) no matter what type the class is. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it does, but only a shallow copy (at least in respect to pointers). Say you have a pointer to another object contained in `Node`, it will not make a copy of the pointed to object, but it will make a copy of node and a copy of the pointer `Node` contains.